# How to prevent landscape orientation in phonegap(html)?

Tags: cordova

I am using following code to prevent landscape orientation in phonegap(html) not pure android.

1.First i am installed "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" plugin in my project folder and then i am include cordova.js and in my program i am include the following line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <script src="cordova.js" type= "text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <h3>hello</h3>
</body>
<script>
     screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
     console.log('Orientation is ' + screen.orientation);
     window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){
     console.log('Orientation changed to ' + screen.orientation);
});
</script>
</html>
```

To compile my program, it gives the following error.

```
E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Screen> has no method 'lockOrientation'
```

How to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Just forget about the plugin and add this line to your config.xml

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

Comment: screen.lockOrientation('landscape');  <= where did you find this? Is it something you made up? You'll need to delete this line.
And technically, your preference in config.xml should be 



```<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />```

Comment: I think that's from this plugin (https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation). Anyway, I think his problem is he calls that method before device ready fires.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you set orientation in manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name=".Android_mobile_infoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Comment: I am not using pure android. I am using html with cordova